# Force .so module to use libc function in case of duplicate functions

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-linking, libc

I'm have .so file that being loaded into binary program address space using LD_PRELOAD mechanism.

The binray program (which is not mine) has it's own implementation for malloc function.

Since my module is being loaded into that program, it uses the program's malloc instead of libc malloc which results crash.

I've complied the binary program myself (it's opensource) and I saw that changing the malloc function to mymalloc function fixes the problem.

Since in production environment I can't change the binary program I want to find other solution.

Is it possible to force .so module to use libc version of malloc (or any other function) in cases where the same function exist in the loading program?

Any help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using ELF symbol versioning. Look at your libc malloc definition:

```
$ objdump -T libc.so | grep malloc
0006fef0 g    DF .text  000001e7  GLIBC_2.0   malloc
```

So if you link your .so file using a linking script such as:

```
GLIBC_2.0 { malloc; };
```

You may get what you want. Assuming, of course that the executable version of `malloc` is not versioned with the same name (not likely).

**CORRECTION**: unfortunately, it does not work! The version is used when defining the symbol. When you use it, it get the version from the exported table. But the one in the executable takes precedence....

**NOTE**: But note that this behavior is by design of the ELF standard. This is to ensure that all the modules in the same process use the same `malloc` function, and so, they can share memory, that is, one module `malloc`, another module `free`. If your so crashes with the program `malloc` then one of two: your so is broken; or the program is broken. If it is the second, then any other module that gets linked would also crash. So maybe you should check your code...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I still can't get it to work. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Unless you find the malloc pointer using dlopen/dlsym, I don't think you can do that. It is simply the privilege of the executable to overwrite any external public symbol. Anyway, are you sure you are not misusing the memory returned by the program's malloc?

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch a pointer to `malloc()` explicitly with `dlsym()`.

```
#define __USE_GNU 1 /* needed for RTLD_NEXT */
#include <dlfcn.h>

void* (*mymalloc)(size_t a);

mymalloc = (void* (*)(size_t)) dlsym (RTLD_NEXT, "malloc");
```

Naturally you must do the same for `free()`, `realloc()` and whatever else you're using.

Comment: I think RTLD_NEXT will return program's malloc, not libc malloc.

Comment: Actually dlsym receives two parameters, the module handle and the symbol, so if you call `void *handle = dlopen("libc.so"); dlsym(handle, "malloc");` you should get it.

Comment: Ugh, my bad. To get programs symbol you have to link it with --export-dynamic. Which actually makes me wonder how LD_PRELOAD'ed library gets overloaded malloc() and isn't a problem exactly because this library uses original malloc from libc()